# macro to use active cell and copy multiple cells to another sheet in different cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy info from one sheet into another using a macro. I'd like to be able to select a cell in Sheet A (eg A10), and using that as a reference copy cells in the same row, eg c10, d10 and g10, and paste that info into static cells in Sheet B, eg $A$6, $A$7, and $A$8.
Have looked through the message boards but haven't found anything that uses the active cell, and multiple cells.
Thanks in advance!
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

The task can be completed using simple statements like the following sample:

```
Worksheets("Sheet A").Range("A10").Copy destination:=Worksheets("Sheet B").Range("$A$6:$A$8")
```

In case you want be able to select a cell in Worksheets("Sheet A") and copy it to the destination Range (as shown above), then you may create a `Sub` like the following one:

```
Sub PasteSelection()
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet B").Range("$A$6:$A$8")
End Sub
```

and call it using, for example, ALT+F8 shortcut to run the Excel VBA macro.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply! I am hoping to automate the cell selection (based on the active cell), and prevent entering the range for each time I copy certain cells across. Each time I will be copying the same cells (column) in a row, and the row will change with Sheet A for each new record, and it will always populate the same cells in sheet B, which I am using to create a pdf invoice, and save each time the macro is finished so I can email it out.

Comment: I would recommend you to clarify your question and add VBA code: you can use the macro recorder, then we would be able to help. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Invoice").Select
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Form responses 1").Select
    Range("D10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Invoice").Select
    Range("B6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Comment: The answer has been given to you pertinent to the cell range in your original question. You can apply it to any other cell range.

Comment: To clarify the q, I have a sheet with customer data. I want to select a row (corresponding to a customer) and then run a macro that takes value form  A6 for example and populates sheet 2 (invoice), b11 (which is the first name), and tehn automatically takes the the value in cell c6 in sheet 1, and copies it into sheet 2, c12, and so on. Hope this helps

Comment: Please see my extended answer. Best regards,

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Is there a way of making that macro copy additional cells with the same action, and pasting to the second sheet? It looks like with your current formula I would have to select the cells to be copied each time. Is that correct?

Comment: You can select the cell just once and copy to multiple Worksheets: just add more statements like: Selection.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet C").Range("$A$6:$A$8") and so on to that macro. Best regards,

Comment: Alex, first time here, so still learning to get the right language. I have 100 customer records, each containing data like name address etc. this is in sheet 1. On sheet 2 I have a invoice template with most of the same fields. I'd like to be able to scroll down the page on sheet 1, choose a customer by selecting the first cell in the row for example, then run the macro which will take the values from column a, b and d in that row and populate the name, address and amount fields in sheet 2. I'll then PDF sheet2, go back to sheet1, select another customer from a diff row and repeat. That help?

Comment: Your question is overly broad and sounds more like a request for software development. As FYI, SO is not intended to be a free code writing service, thus I would recommend you to prototype your solution by yourself (you may use VBA Macro recorder, for e.g.) and post a specific question pertinent to the problematic part of that code. You may accept the answer 'as is' or not, but I am closing this discussion thread now as it's getting too lengthy. Good luck with your project. Best regards,